# If I know Windows kernel, what can I do?

Tags: windows, kernel

Currently I am in a stage that can learn Windows kernel programming, but I am wondering after that which types of jobs I can do?

For Linux kernel, seems till now only a bunch of driver works related jobs there.

Comment: You could probably find a job in the malware "industry". :p

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could write low level code that interacted with it (optimization purposes I assume).
Also drivers like the Linux world as well.

Answer (score 12):

There are quite a few jobs for people who can write Windows drivers, but most of them are not at traditional software companies -- rather, they're at companies that produce hardware that needs to work with Windows.

There is also the possibility of writing Native API code that bypasses Win32, and talks to the Windows NT kernel directly. For the most part, MS seems to officially frown on people doing this -- but when they do it well (e.g. the former ntinernals.com) MS buys them up and apparently puts them to work for MS (assuming somebody else doesn't first, of course).

The bottom line is that it is a useful skill set, but not particularly likely to be a life-changing event, or anything on that order. Also keep in mind that writing kernel code *is* writing kernel code -- doing it well goes way beyond the usual definition of "meticulous". A good kernel code is a guy who routinely has to sit back down and physically relax, because he's so anal retentive that the first time he stood up, the chair stuck to his butt!